# Sharing raw input with multiple scripts

Tags: input, sharing

Basically I have a few scripts and a main script to control two other scripts. I am taking in raw input from my main script and I want to share the raw input with my two other scripts.

I have an if statement to also take in a user option so if the user entered option 1 then it would call script1 and execute it but for this work I need to send another piece of raw input to script 1 for it to send.

main.py
    import script1

```
print 'Please enter filename'
filename = raw_input()

print 'Please enter option'
option = raw_input()

if option == '1':
    script1.main()
```

I want the filename data to be sent to script1. I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `script1.main()` an input argument. This will allow you to pass in `filename` or anything else you chose.

Comment: That worked, I'm sure I tried this earlier but it didn't work for some reason.. I must have over complicated it. Thanks a lot :)